# Probability of sub-probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have 3 clients whose advertising is shown in some mobile app. Each client has a list of ads that can be shown with equal probability. As a concrete example:

- Client A is featured 20% of the time, and has 5 ads
- Client B is featured 30% of the time, and has 10 ads
- Client C is featured 50% of the time, and has 15 ads

So given an arbitrary pageview, there is a 50% chance that client C will have one of its 15 ads displayed to the user.

**Question**

How do I calculate the probability of a specific ad from client C being displayed?

How do I express ((1 out of 15) out of 50%) in terms of the overall probability?

Comment: If all the ads are equally likely to show, then your probablity will be $$\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{15}$$.

Comment: That looks simple enough. How do I know when to multiply the odds of both events, and when to add them?

Comment: You multiply when you require two events occurring simultaneously. In this case, (Pick client C) **and** (Pick the one out of 15 ads).
You add when you are considering different cases of an event happening.

Comment: Is this an example of "considering different cases of an event happening": what's the prob. that ad 3 from client A is chosen OR ad 7 from client B?

Comment: Yes, it is. For a similar, albeit slightly complex example, suppose ad 3 of client A and ad 7 of client B are the same. Then your event gets divided as (Choose client A _and_ ad 3) **or** (Choose client B _and_ ad 7).